# JQuery - determine if ALL multiple select box items are selected?

Tags: jquery

What is the easiest way to determine if ALL items in a multiple HTML select box are selected?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can check the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) of [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) `<option>` elements, for example:

```
var allSelected = $("#selectID option:not(:selected)").length == 0;
```

Comment: Dumb question - how would you write this a generalized function where you could pass in a variable representing your select box (#selectID in your example).  Ie: `var allSelected = func("#selbox");`

Comment: @Marcus - you can concatenate the string: `$("#" + passedInID + "  option:not(:selected)")`

Comment: Sweet.  :)    +1 for the one-liner flair.

Comment: @NickCraver : What is the best way to write this function if it accepts the jquery select object itself and not the id? Do we have to get the id and use the concatenation technique as you suggested?

Comment: Just found that we can use the jquery object directly as follows `$("option:not(:selected)", jqObj).length`

Comment: @Somu - yep, or the equivalent that gets turned into internally: `jqObj.find("option:not(:selected)").length`

Comment: On which event of check box should the generalized function be called?

Answer (score 1):

check if the number of not selected is zero and if there are at least 1 option

```
var all = $("select :not(:selected)").length == 0 && $("select options").length > 0;
```

Comment: Where did the "these must be at least one present" requirement come from?  If none are there, 0 still means all possible options are checked.